# How can i pass the spinner value from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android

I have an android studio assignment that requires us to create 3 activities, one of these activities has a spinner and text and we must pass the text and selected spinner value from the activity to another activity to show the input I figured out how to pass the text but I can't quite figure how to do the same to the spinner. this is the spinner code.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Homepage<adapter> extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Button btn;
    EditText et;
    String st;
    String selectedItem="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.Btnstart);
        et = findViewById(R.id.Std_Name);
        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.major_spinner);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                       Intent i = new Intent(Homepage.this, Input.class);
                                       st = et.getText().toString();
                                       i.putExtra("Value", st);
                                       startActivity(i);
                                       finish();
                                   }
                               });

        /**

                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Homepage.this, Input.class);
                        selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        intent.putExtra("selectedItem", selectedItem);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
         **/



        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.majors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `text` variable to the scope of the activity and pass in the `Intent`, like you did with your `st` variable.